# ¿Cómo centralizo la ventana al iniciar usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

import tkinter as tk

class App():

```
def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.window = tk.Tk()
    self.window.wm_title("Test")
    self.window.wm_geometry("900x600")
    self.window.configure(background = "black")
    self.window.wm_resizable(False, False)
    self.window = tk.mainloop()
```

app = App()

"""Es un ejemplo modelo este código. Lo que quiero saber es cómo centralizar la ventana al correr la aplicación, porque aparece aleatoriamente en el monitor y lo que quiero es que quede centrada al arrancar, hay alguna forma?"""

Comment: Te sirve esta respuesta del sitio en inglés? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018670/12913664

Comment: Gracias, Dante S.

Comment: De nada Ulises c:

Answer (score 0):

¿Como andas?

```
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.wm_title("Test")
        self.window.wm_geometry("900x600+550+300")
        self.window.configure(background = "black")
        self.window.wm_resizable(False, False)
        self.window = tk.mainloop()

App()
```

Bueno, en `self.window.wm_geometry` podes sumar dos numeros despues de la resolucion para posicionar la ventana de Tkinter en la pantalla.

Por deduccion, pienso que esos 2 numeros serian la posicion X, Y en la pantalla.

Comment: Gracias, callahanito, me sirvió.